# Android view.setid(View.generateViewId()) does not work. It cannot find the view attached to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, fragment

I try to insert a fragment (frag_bannerAds; frag_bannerAds contains another recyclerView actually) into one item of a recyclerView defined in a fragment file V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag.java (fragInst). The fragment frag_bannerAds is allocated in V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag.java (fragInst). I encounter a crash with below error when I smoothScroll the recyclerView. The weird thing is that it does not crash in real phone device. It crashed in Android emulator AVD (Pixel 3, API 27, x86). But it works fine in mulator AVD (Nexus 5, API 23, x86). It also crashed in Android emulator AVD (Pixel 3, API 29, x86_64).

Why is view id generated by  newId = View.generateViewId() cannot find the view it attached to assgined by frag_bannerAds.setId(newId);?
What I am missing?
Why some device and emulator do not crash and work fine?

Output and error message:

----banner, after setId, frag_bannerAds=android.widget.FrameLayout{5f09291 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #4}

----banner, after bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId=4

-----  fragInst.frag_bannerAds = V_Room_Pub_Banner_Frag{13cc5f6} (ec17bc37-7e02-4431-bb07-ca47dfbc3a5f)}

--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test1385, PID: 6612
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4 (unknown) for fragment V_Room_Pub_Banner_Frag{13cc5f6} (ec17bc37-7e02-4431-bb07-ca47dfbc3a5f) id=0x4 tag-abcd}
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.K(SourceFile:27)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.I(SourceFile:1)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.J(Unknown Source:47)

In V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag.java  :

```
     private V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag   mContext_fragInst  ;
     private List<V_Room_Pub_LS_Data> chatList;  
     public V_Room_Pub_Banner_Frag  frag_bannerAds ;         
     ....
     frag_bannerAds =   V_Room_Pub_Banner_Frag.newInstance();  
             //  allocte the fragment to be inserted here 
     ....
     mContext_fragInst = this ; 
     ...
     // define  recylerView 
    chatList = ...  ; 
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext_this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
    chatRecyclerView    = view.findViewById(R.id.chat_container);
    chatRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    chatAdapter         = new V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter(mContext_fragInst, dbTableVar, chatList );
    chatRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    chatRecyclerView.setMediaList(chatList, layoutManager);  
    ...
```

In Adapter file  V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.java :

```
    ...
    private V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag  fragInst;
    private List<V_Room_Pub_LS_Data> chatList; 
    ...

    public V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter(V_Room_Pub_LS_Frag fragInst, String dbTableVar, List<V_Room_Pub_LS_Data> chatList) {
         this.fragInst = fragInst;
         this.dbTableVar  = dbTableVar;  this.chatList  = chatList;
    }

    @Override
    public V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View  view ;
        V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.ItemViewHolder   itemViewHolder;
        switch (viewType) {
            case ViewType_Item:
            default:
                view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.v_room_pub_ls_item, parent, false);
                itemViewHolder = new V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.ItemViewHolder(view , ViewType_Item);
                break;

            case ViewType_BannerAd:
                view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.v_room_pub_ls_banner_ads, parent, false);
                itemViewHolder = new V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.ItemViewHolder(view , ViewType_BannerAd);
                break;
        }
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final V_Room_Pub_LS_Adapter.ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, final int i) {
        final V_Room_Pub_LS_Data chatMsg = chatList.get(i);
        if( chatMsg.getViewType() == ViewType_BannerAd ){
            Log.d("fg_ccc","-----  fragInst.frag_bannerAds = "+ fragInst.frag_bannerAds ) ;
            fragInst.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                    itemViewHolder.bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId, 
                    fragInst.frag_bannerAds, "tag-abcd").commit();
            return ; 
        }
        ....
    }

   public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     FrameLayout  frag_bannerAds ;
     int          bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId;
     ...
     public ItemViewHolder(View itemView, Integer viewType) {
        super(itemView)
        if( viewType == ViewType_BannerAd ) {
            frag_bannerAds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bannerads_list_frag); 
            // R.id.bannerads_list_frag is a frameLayout in  R.layout.v_room_pub_ls_banner_ads
            
            bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId = View.generateViewId();   //  4 is generated 
            
            frag_bannerAds.setId(bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId);
            
            Log.d("fg_ccc", "----banner, after setId, frag_bannerAds=" + frag_bannerAds);
            Log.d("fg_ccc", "----banner, after bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId=" + bannerAds_fragView_newUniqueId);
            return ; 
        } 
        ... 
        ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

onBindViewHolder
There seems to be a way to create a fragment and replace it by default. When I implemented the RecyclerView multi-layout before, because it was not created by default,Of course, this is just my personal suggestion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I advise against putting fragments in a RecyclerView.  Particularly fragments which are switched out.  The way a RecyclerView works is by creating a static set of views for a given item type.  By doing fragment tranactions inside of it, you violate that assumption and will break the ability to recycle views properly.  A static fragment *might* work, although I wouldn't suggest it and I'm not sure RecyclerView wouldn't screw up the lifecycle.  But it should never be replaced out.

The correct way to do this is to use different item types for the different types of fragments you wish to display.  Then instantiate the correct type of view in onCreateView for the different types.

Comment: I did use item types for different fragments. The issue is some emulators do not recognize  framelayout.setId(newId) in ItemViewHolder class.  It does not recognize the view later. But older emulators work.

Comment: @user2818066 Preferably you don't use fragments in a RecyclerView at all.  But if you must try (and they're not made to be put in one, so the lifecycle may be screwed if you do), there's no reason to ever use setId. Because you would NEVER be using replace to switch it out, because there's no reason to ever switch it out.  You'd only use a static fragment.